# Get active chrome url using C#

Tags: .net, google-chrome

I found this solution:

```
        Process[] procsChrome = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
        foreach (Process chrome in procsChrome)
        {
            // the chrome process must have a window
            if (chrome.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // find the automation element
            AutomationElement elm = AutomationElement.FromHandle(chrome.MainWindowHandle);
            AutomationElementCollection elmUrlBars = elm.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants,
              new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, ""));

            // if it can be found, get the value from the URL bar
            if (elmUrlBars != null)
            {
                foreach (AutomationElement item in elmUrlBars)
                {
                    AutomationPattern[] patterns = item.GetSupportedPatterns();
                    if (patterns.Length > 0)
                    {
                        ValuePattern val = (ValuePattern)item.GetCurrentPattern(patterns[0]);
                        Console.WriteLine("Chrome URL found: " + val.Current.Value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

but in is not working in last chrome version (34.0.1847.131 m).
Can somebody tell more common solution?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish that requires you to read the "active Chrome URL"?

Comment: I need to know, current active chrome url, I know it's can be done by writing chrome extensions but it's not a solution for me. All other logic is on .net.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this solution in my case it works fine.**

```
string GetChromeUrl(IntPtr hndl)
        {
            if (hndl.ToInt32() > 0)
            {
                string url = "";
                AutomationElement elm = AutomationElement.FromHandle(hndl);
                AutomationElement elmUrlBar = elm.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants,
                  new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Address and search bar"));
                if (elmUrlBar != null)
                {
                    AutomationPattern[] patterns = elmUrlBar.GetSupportedPatterns();
                    if (patterns.Length > 0)
                    {
                        ValuePattern val = (ValuePattern)elmUrlBar.GetCurrentPattern(patterns[0]);
                        url = val.Current.Value;
                        return url;
                    }
                }

            }
            return "";
        }
```

Comment: Why does this work? Give a bit of explanation as this will minimize copying and pasting without understanding.  Code dumping without some form of explanation is (usually) discouraged on StackOverflow.

Comment: refer "inspect.exe"   in windows where you found the "LegacyIAccessible.Name" and "LegacyIAccessible.Value" property and the parameter for this property is "Address and search bar""which returns the active URL of Chrome browser.

Comment: how to call this method?

Answer (score 0):

This is an elegant way to get focused window URL for you guys reference.

```
    public string GetBrowserUrl()
    {
        AutomationElement focusedElement = AutomationElement.FocusedElement;

        if (focusedElement != null)
        {
            object pattern;
            if (focusedElement.TryGetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern, out pattern))
            {
                var valuePattern = (ValuePattern)pattern;
                string currentUrl = valuePattern.Current.Value;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentUrl))
                {
                    return currentUrl;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I had test it on chrome, edge, firefox and explorer. It work fine with me.